# Material UI - Make Footer stick to Bottom but not overlap Content

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am creating a Webapp with React and the Material UI Framework. I created a Footer and now this Footer should be at the bottom when the Page Content is smaller than the screen height. But when the Page Content is bigger than the screen height, the Footer should not be always visible and so block parts of the content. It should then be at the bottom of the Page Content.

I tried to use { position: 'absolute', bottom: 0 } at the root  from the Footer Component, but with that the footer always sticked to the bottom, overlapped content and most of the right side of the footer was outside of the page.
Also i tried multiple other "solutions" from other posts to the same question but none of these worked.

This is my App.tsx where the Routes, Navbar and also the Footer are located. Every Component there is wrapped inside a MUI Container:

```
return (
    <>
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
            <CssBaseline />
            <Container sx={{ p: 2 }}>
                <INavbar />
                <Routes>
                    <Route path='/' element={<IHome />} />

                    <Route path='*' element={<INotFound />} />
                </Routes>
                <IFooter />
            </Container>
        </ThemeProvider>
    </>
)
```

Now this is my Footer.tsx:

```
return (
    <>
        <Box
            sx={{
                width: '100%',
                py: 4,
            }}
        >
            <Box>
                
            </Box>
            <Box
                sx={{
                    borderTop: '1px solid rgb(58, 61, 64)',
                    pt: 5,
                    display: 'flex',
                    flexDirection: 'row',
                    justifyContent: 'space-between',
                    alignItems: 'center',
                    px: 2,
                    [theme.breakpoints.down('md')]: {
                        flexDirection: 'column',
                        alignItems: 'center'
                    }
                }}
            >
                <Typography
                    sx={{
                        mb: { xs: 1, md: 0 },
                        textAlign: { xs: 'left', md: 'center' },
                        color: 'rgb(187, 197, 208)'
                    }}
                >
                    © {new Date().getFullYear()} ・ Company
                </Typography>
                <Box
                    sx={{
                        display: 'flex',
                        flexDirection: 'row',
                        justifyContent: 'flex-end'
                    }}
                >
                    <Link
                        sx={{
                            color: 'rgb(187, 197, 208)',
                            transition: '0.5s',
                            ":hover": { color: '#0088a9' },
                            textDecoration: 'none',
                            mr: { xs: 2, md: 6 },
                            mb: { xs: 0, md: 1 }
                        }}
                        href="/impressum"
                    >
                        IMPRESSUM
                    </Link>
                    <Link
                        sx={{
                            color: 'rgb(187, 197, 208)',
                            transition: '0.5s',
                            ":hover": { color: '#0088a9' },
                            textDecoration: 'none',
                            mb: { xs: 0, md: 1 }
                        }}
                        href="/datenschutz"
                    >
                        DATENSCHUTZ
                    </Link>
                </Box>
            </Box>
        </Box>
    </>
)
```